# Google map code dosent holds the maps on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display google maps on my page. I tried with HTML code but its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
     <h1>My First Google Map</h1>
     <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
     <script>
       function myMap() {
        var mapProp= {
           center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
           zoom:10,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
       }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY& callback=myMap"></script>
   </body>  
</html>
```

This is the code that I was trying but once the map is displayed it gets removed after few seconds.

Comment: using iframe may work here

Answer (score 1):

Google requires an API key, which need to be hand over in the Url.

`js?key=YOUR_KEY`you need to replace YOUR_KEY with the API key to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use google map in your site, you should first register your domain(www.yourwebsitename.com) to google maps at [https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?apis=maps] and they provide you a **key**

Place that key instead of YOUR_KEY and you're done with the job

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY& callback=myMap"></script>
```